# Is it possible to fill in SearchInput with data from current endpoint?

Tags: react-admin

React-admin documentation suggests to filter data via referencing to another endpoint like:

```
    <Filter {...props}>
        <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
        <ReferenceInput
            label="User"
            source="userId"
            reference="users"
            allowEmpty
        >
            <SelectInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </Filter>
```

But in my case there is no need to refer to another endpoint and I would like to filter current list relying on data from this list:

```
  <Filter {...props}>
    <SelectInput label='Title' source='Title' allowEmpty/>
  </Filter>
```

But the filter list is empty. How can I data from "title"? I will be grateful for any possible help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ReferenceInput` will set the `choices` property of the `SelectInput`. If you want to use the `SelectInput` alone, you need to provide a `choices` property by yourself like

```
<SelectInput
  choices={items.map(({ id, name }) => ({
    id,
    name
  }))}
  label="My Select"
  source="userId"
/>
```